# Using Python and Webhose.io to crawl web data into son format

Tags: python, web-crawler, webhose

I'm new to Python. What I'm trying to do is to use the Webhose.io API to crawl web data into Json format. Each query will give me 5 posts/articles. I'm trying to get 1000 articles for the dataset.

Webhose are free to register and will give you 1000 request per month for free, so this should be enough for getting the dataset.

The code I have currently looke like this:

```
import webhoseio, json, io

webhoseio.config(token="YOUR API KEY")

query_params = {
"q": "organization:Amazon",
"sort": "crawled"
}

results = webhoseio.query("filterWebContent", query_params)

print(len(results))

with open('dataset.txt','w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
output = json.dumps(results,
                    indent=4, sort_keys=True,
                    separators=(',', ': '), ensure_ascii=False)

outfile.write(output)
#output = json.load(outfile)
results = webhoseio.get_next()
output += json.dumps(results,
                    indent=4, sort_keys=True,
                    separators=(',', ': '), ensure_ascii=False)
outfile.write(output)
```

Each time I ran the code, looks like I'm only using 1 request. I'm not sure how many articles I'm getting. Is there a way to modify the code so that I can get 1000 articles (5 articles per request, need 200 requests) and also is there a way to change the crawled date in Webhose so that the 200 request won't give me the same articles.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The content (articles, metadata) of the first 100 posts of your query is stored in `results['posts']`. So when you call `len(results['posts'])` you should get a 100 (Assuming your query produces at least 100 results.)
To get the next 100 results you should call `webhoseio.get_next()`.
To get all batches you could do something like

```
output = [] 
while True:
    temp = webhoseio.get_next()
    output = output+temp['posts']
    if temp['moreResultsAvailable'] <= 0:
        break
```